# Numpy speed up creation of 2 dimensional array

Tags: performance, numpy

I have a function `fn(s)` which converts a string to 1-dim np.array of the size `(1281,)`. Now I need to convert `X` such strings to get an 2-dim np.array of size `(X, 1281)`. I can easily achieve this with `np.stack([fn(s) for s in arr_s], axis=0)`.

The only problem is that my X is approximately 10^6 and the whole thing runs too long. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Share implementation of `fn`?

Comment: @Divakar the implementation of `fn` is very complicated. Basically it uses a python chess library to convert a [fen position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) to a float vector. Is it possible to do it having a general `fn`?

Comment: Well vectorizing usually makes sense when done on the function that is iterated. So, it might be difficult for a generic func.

Comment: @Divakar I can share the function, but it is pretty complicated. Not sure whether it will help.

Comment: @SalvadorDali If the structure of your function allows it you could try to run a profiler on the function and see if a specific part of the funcion is being slow. Then just share a boiled down version of the function.

Comment: Our guess is that most of the time is spent in evaluating `fn` 10^6 times.  The looping mechanism and `vstack` are probably a minor time factor.